# 500 internal server error Akka Nginx

Tags: nginx, akka, internal-server-error

I am trying to run Akka service using nginx. Here is my default.conf:

```
upstream hello-akka{
    server localhost:9000;
}

server {
    listen 9000;

    location /* {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /akka {
        proxy_pass http://hello-akka;
    }

    location /assets {
        root /var/www;
    }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }   
}
```

Default nginx page works just fine but when I redirect to /akka I get **500 internal server error**. Here is my nginx log file:

```
2017/12/05 10:58:17 [crit] 11077#11077: *1014 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (24: Too many open files), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /akka HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/akka", host: "hello-akka"
```

I have changed /etc/security/limits.con file to increase the number of connections from 1024 to 16384. However, after that I keep getting another error:

```
host: "hello-akka"
2017/12/05 11:40:42 [error] 15916#15916: *37494 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /akka HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/akka"
```

So what is wrong with my configurations and how should I change them to run /akka page normally?

UPDATE: I have changed `server localhost:9000` to `server localhost:8080` in upstream hello-akka. However, when I redirect to localhost:9000/akka I get **An error occurred** page.
Error logs shows this error:

```
*1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /akka HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/akka", host: "localhost:9000"
```

Comment: Are you trying to run nginx on port 9000 and the backend "Akka" server on 9000? They can't both listen on localhost:9000.

Comment: Ok. And how should I change the file- just set another port for hello-akka?

Comment: I can't say if it's the only issue, but yes, it looks to me like either nginx or akka should have their port changed. If you change the Akka port, you'd have to change it in Akka and nginx's upstream server config.

Comment: @mjb2kmn I have updated my question

Comment: Can you connect to http://127.0.0.1:8080/akka directly without nginx?

Comment: Yeah, it works without nginx. Also, after I have changed the ports and ran my web service again it has started to work. Thank you very much!!